# Comparing multidimensional string arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, compare

So I have 2 sets of `string[9,9]` arrays, and I would like to compare them, but `array1.Cast<string>.SequenceEqual(array2.Cast<string>);` gives me an error under the `.Cast<string>` saying it's a method, which is not valid in the given context.

is there any better way to compare two multidimensional arrays of strings?

Comment: It should be `.Cast<string>()`, not `.Cast<string>`. In both places

Comment: I input both of them to be the same, but for whatever reason, it still came out false

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: if youve done what Rob commented and you still have problem in results then you have to show how you populate those arrays with an example.

Comment: @Rob Linq methods do not work on 2d+ arrays at all.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Actually, `.Cast<string>()` does infact work on multi-dimensional arrays.. try it :)

Comment: @Rob you indeed right - `Cast` works on `IEnumerable` (unlike other methods that expect `IEnumerable<T>`)... But that would not be really good comparison of arrays as it will ignore dimensions - 3x4 would be the same as 4x3 or 2x2x3... Otherwise `(new int[3,4]).Cast<int>().SequenceEqual((new int[4,3]).Cast<int>())` compiles/returns true.